# некорректная работа phpmail

Tags: email

здравствуйте, я отправляю письма функцией php mail() со своей ВПС (Centos 7)

но у меня есть проблема, письма попадают в спам, либо вообще не доходят (на mail.ru к примеру), стоит только postfix, скажите как можно решить эту проблему? спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте ваш IP-адрес сервера, находится ли он в черных списках (например, через https://mxtoolbox.com). У Mail.ru более жесткая система фильтрации, так что не исключаю, что там письма просто отклоняются из-за подозрительного адреса.

Также, чтобы улучшить проходимость писем настройте правильно DKIM, SPF и DMARC. Посмотреть что именно думает о вашем сервере Mail.ru можно через их сервис https://postmaster.mail.ru